# Navigate from a class to another screen using React Navigation (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am attempting to use react navigation in class. I normally use it in functions like this:

```
//imports...
export default function Page1({navigation}) {
//...
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Page2')}}
//...
}
```

`onPress` is inside `TouchableOpacity`. Now I want to use it in class like this:

```
//imports...
export default class Page3 extends React.Component {
//...
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Page4')}}
//...
}
```

I dont know how to pass `{navigation}` to class Page3. Is there a way to do this?
This is my App.js

```
//...
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

import Page1 from './src/Page1';
import Page2 from './src/Page2';
import Page3 from './src/Page3';
import Page4 from './src/Page4';

export default function App() {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen component={Page1} name="Page1" options={{headerShown:false}}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen component={Page2} name="Page2" options={{headerShown:false}}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen component={Page3} name="Page3" options={{headerShown:false}}></Stack.Screen>
          <Stack.Screen component={Page4} name="Page4" options={{headerShown:false}}></Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using class components, use `this.props`

```
//imports...
export default class Page3 extends React.Component {
//...
onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Page4')}}
//...
}
```

EXPLANATION:

So basically in a functional component, in order to access navigation you have say {navigation} on the parameter on top of the function.

```
//imports...
export default function Page1({navigation}) {
//...
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Page2')}}
//...
}
```

Instead of having the brackets on the arguments, you can say `props`. Props is basically sending data from one component to another.

```
//imports...
export default function Page1(props) {
const {navigation} = props; // aka const navigation = props.navigation. Both are same
//...
onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Page2')}}
//...
}
```

Note that you can also say without having to make the variable(You can try this if you have a functional component it will work)

```
onPress={()=> {props.navigation.navigate('Page2')}}
```

So, in our case, it's a class component. What's so special about class components is that the props are auto "imported" to the class and it is global meaning that you can access this by using `this`. So it would be `this.props`

Just like a functional component you can do:

```
export default class Page3 extends React.Component {
//... functions

render(){

const {navigation} = this.props; // make sure you have in this render() but outside of return.

// that is also equalavent of saying const navigation = this.props.navigation


return (
   //...
   onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate('Page4')}}
   //...

)
  }
}
```

Hope this makes sense. Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: Do I need to pass ```{navigation}```? And how can I do that?

Comment: No need to. Just do that and it should work

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Would you mind explaining how this works, I don't understand it.

Comment: See above. I've added explanations

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

For the class component, you need to use

```
onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate('Page4')}}
```

Using your example I create snack so that you will understand everything
[Snack Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@100rabhchavan/passing-parameters-to-routes-%7C-react-navigation) click on it and check the perfect solution.

for page1,page2,page4 I used the function component and
for the page3 I used the class component so that,
you will understand  difference between class and function component.

Comment: Thank you so much